# How to pass data to a custom widget from kv language

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want to pass a variable to the class of a custom widget to construct it.

Python:

```
class Customwidget(BoxLayout)
        mystring = StringProperty()
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(Customwidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            print(mystring)
```

Kivy

```
Root:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Customwidget:
            mystring: 'stringcontents'
```

When this is executed, mystring remains empty. How do I pass it to the class such that it can be used within **init** for logic in defining the widget's contents?

Answer (score 0):

## Problem - empty string

> When this is executed, mystring remains empty. How do I pass it to the
>   class such that it can be used within init for logic in defining the
>   widget's contents?

## Root Cause

> The [`load_kv()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv) function is called from [run()](http://This%20function%20is%20called%20from%20run(),%20therefore,), therefore,
>   any widget whose styling is defined in this kv file and is created
>   before [run()](http://This%20function%20is%20called%20from%20run(),%20therefore,) is called (e.g. in `__init__`), won’t have its styling
>   applied. Note that [build()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.build) is called after [load_kv](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.load_kv) has been
>   called.

## Solution

Use Kivy Clock [`schedule_once()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.CyClockBase.schedule_once) method to invoke the `print()` function after Kivy completed styling.

### Snippets

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(Customwidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: print(f"mystring={self.mystring}"), 0.02)
```

### Example

#### main.py

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock


class Customwidget(BoxLayout):
    mystring = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Customwidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: print(f"mystring={self.mystring}"), 0.02)


runTouchApp(Builder.load_string("""
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Customwidget:
            mystring: 'stringcontents'
"""))
```